# How to find exact GPU details on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, gpu

I have an NVidia 750 GTX Ti and an NVidia 1050 GTX (may be or not be Titatium)
The are installed in PCI slots in my Gigabyte gaming motherboard.

However, all I seem to be able to obtain with lspci, lshw, and nvidia-smi - is identification of the first board seen - the 1050 GTX.

I'm using the nvidia driver

```
lspci | grep vga 
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] (rev a1)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] (rev a1)
```

These should *not* be identical

Comment: These are two GPUs in two different slots.

Comment: Have you tried `inxi -G` or `neofetch`?

Comment: I'd like to note that a few things I saw others mention so far, e.g. `lspci`, and `inxi -G` will tell you how the currently enabled _driver_ managed to identify / categorize / classify your piece of hardware. But it's not necessarily the exact model, or not how the piece of hardware would introduce itself, if it could. Rather, it's what the driver said "It's the closest match I can find in my inventory that matches the feature set that the card reports about itself". (I don't have experience with `nvidia-smi`, so I don't know whether it works with a different concept.)

Comment: For the above reason, I, as someone who bought some laptop with some ultra obcure, small-series, evolutionary dead-end dedicated graphics card, which the open source driver had no chance identifying accurately, I had to determine the exact graphics card model by consulting the hardware component manifest that my laptop manufacturer provides on their product support webpage.

Answer (score 1):

If you run

```
lspci -nn | grep VGA
```

you'll get vendor and product codes. If they are identical, then the GPU chips are identical.

Comment: Online version: https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/  :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you've installed the nvidia driver the following command should help you:

```
nvidia-smi
```

It shows sth like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.161.03   Driver Version: 470.161.03   CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:1C:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| 34%   42C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    449MiB /  4029MiB |     N/A      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

`inxi -G`

would be another candidate:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GK104 [GeForce GTX 760] driver: nvidia v: 470.161.03
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.6 driver: X: loaded: nvidia
    gpu: nvidia,nvidia-nvswitch resolution: 1: 2560x1440~60Hz 2: 1920x1080~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 470.161.03 renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX
    760/PCIe/SSE2
```

Comment: `inxi` was able to describe the exact NVIDIA name of the GPU I had on my laptop. Thanks